# The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, base64

So I have an azure function that encodes an object in Base64 before putting it on an azure queue and then the object is decoded and deserilized in the next function.
The code for encoding it and sending it is here:

```
var trackIdAndUserid = new TrackIdAndUserId { TrackId = track.Track.Id, UserId = track.UserId };
var message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(trackIdAndUserid);
buffer = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
string msg = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
await queueClient.SendMessageAsync(msg);
```

An example message on the queue is

```
ewAiAFQAcgBhAGMAawBJAGQAIgA6ACIAMABpADQAbgBIAGEANwB3AEwAQwBYADEAMQBNADcAeQBJAHAANwBpAFQASgAiACwAIgBVAHMAZQByAEkAZAAiADoAIgAzADgAMAA5AGYANQBjADMALQA4ADEANABmAC0ANABmADYAYwAtAGIAYwAzAGMALQBhAGYANgA3AGYANAAwAGQAMwBlADMAZgAiAH0A
```

The code to decode it is here:

```
byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(myQueueItemStringBase64);
string myQueueItemString = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer);
var myQueueItem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TrackIdAndUserId>(myQueueItemString);
```

Comment: It seems to be completely valid base64 to me I dont get why it throws an error

Comment: So when I manually queue the base64 encoded data I don't get an error but its just when it comes straight from the first azure function

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding a queue client options and setting the encoding in the options to base64

```
var queueClient = new QueueClient(configuration["AzureWebJobsStorage"], "add-track-to-cosmos", new QueueClientOptions { MessageEncoding = QueueMessageEncoding.Base64});
```